# modifying python path permanently

Tags: python, function, anaconda, libraries, pythonpath

I want to permanently add a directory to the path to load the functions and modules that I will create in the future.

For example:
C:\Users\XXX\Lib1

Inside it there would be a structure similar to the following one:

```
Lib1/    
    /m1/__init__.py
        1.py
        2.py
    /m2/__init__.py
        a.py
        b.py
```

I want to use the libraries independently of where the current file path is located (ex: import lib1... m2.a(x,x,x) )

I'm using python 3 with anaconda3 on windows 10

Using the following commands, I achieve my objective, but when I close python the changes are not saved. I have to run them every time I open python again.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\Users\XXX\Lib1')
```

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

Set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  Use `setx` to modify the user environment from a command prompt.  Add `/M` switch if you want to modify the system environment (all users).  See `setx /?` for other options.

```
setx PYTHONPATH c:\users\xxx\lib1
```